# How to implement fault tolerant file upload with akka remote and steam

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream

I'm an Akka beginner. (I am using Java)

I'm making a file transfer system using Akka.

Currently, I have completed sending the Actor1(Local) -> Actor2(Remote) file.

Now,

When I have a problem transferring files, I'm thinking about how to solve it.
Then I had a question. The questions are as follows.

If I lost my network connection while I was transferring files, the file transfer failed (90 percent complete).
I will recover my network connection a few minutes later.

Is it possible to transfer the rest of the file data? (10% Remaining)

If that's possible, Please give me some advice.

here is my simple code.
thanks :)

Actor1 (Local)

```
private Behavior<Event> onTick() {
    ....
    String fileName = "test.zip";
    Source<ByteString, CompletionStage<IOResult>> logs = FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get(fileName));
    logs.runForeach(f -> originalSize += f.size(), mat).thenRun(() -> System.out.println("originalSize : " + originalSize));
    SourceRef<ByteString> logsRef = logs.runWith(StreamRefs.sourceRef(), mat);
    getContext().ask(
            Receiver.FileTransfered.class,
            selectedReceiver,
            timeout,
            responseRef -> new Receiver.TransferFile(logsRef, responseRef, fileName),
            (response, failure) -> {
                if (response != null) {
                    return new TransferCompleted(fileName, response.transferedSize);
                } else {
                    return new JobFailed("Processing timed out", fileName);
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Actor2 (Remote)

```
public static Behavior<Command> create() {
    return Behaviors.setup(context -> {
        ...
        Materializer mat = Materializer.createMaterializer(context);
        return Behaviors.receive(Command.class)
                .onMessage(TransferFile.class, command -> {
                    command.sourceRef.getSource().runWith(FileIO.toPath(Paths.get("test.zip")), mat);
                    command.replyTo.tell(new FileTransfered("filename", 1024));
                    return Behaviors.same();
                }).build();
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you interested in solution in scala?

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc If you give me the solution, I will refer to it as much as possible. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to think about following for a proper implementation of file transfer with fault tolerance:

1. How to identify that a transfer has to be resumed for a given ***file***.
2. How to find the ***point*** from which to resume the transfer.

Following implementation makes very simple assumptions about 1 and 2.

1. The file name is unique and thus can be used for such identification. Strictly speaking, this is not true, for example you can transfer files with the same name from different folders. Or from different nodes, etc. You will have to readjust this based on your use case.
2. It is assumed that the last/all writes on the receiver side wrote all bytes correctly and total number of written bytes indicate the point to resume the transfer. If this cannot be guaranteed, you need to logically split the original file into chunks and transfer hashes of each chunk, its size and position to the receiver, which has to validate chunks on its side and find correct pointer for resuming the transfer.
3. (That's a bit more than 2 :) ) This implementation ignores identification of transfer problem and focuses on 1 and 2 instead.

The code:

```scala
object Sender {
  sealed trait Command
  case class Upload(file: String) extends Command
  case class StartWithIndex(file: String, index: Long) extends Sender.Command

  def behavior(receiver: ActorRef[Receiver.Command]): Behavior[Sender.Command] = Behaviors.setup[Sender.Command] { ctx =>
    implicit val materializer: Materializer = SystemMaterializer(ctx.system).materializer
    Behaviors.receiveMessage {
      case Upload(file) =>
        receiver.tell(Receiver.InitUpload(file, ctx.self.narrow[StartWithIndex]))
        ctx.log.info(s"Initiating upload of $file")
        Behaviors.same
      case StartWithIndex(file, starWith) =>
        val source = FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get(file), chunkSize = 8192, starWith)
        val ref = source.runWith(StreamRefs.sourceRef())
        ctx.log.info(s"Starting upload of $file")
        receiver.tell(Receiver.Upload(file, ref))
        Behaviors.same
    }
  }
}
```

```scala
object Receiver {
  sealed trait Command

  case class InitUpload(file: String, replyTo: ActorRef[Sender.StartWithIndex]) extends Command

  case class Upload(file: String, fileSource: SourceRef[ByteString]) extends Command

  val behavior: Behavior[Receiver.Command] = Behaviors.setup[Receiver.Command] { ctx =>
    implicit val materializer: Materializer = SystemMaterializer(ctx.system).materializer
    Behaviors.receiveMessage {
      case InitUpload(path, replyTo) =>
        val file = fileAtDestination(path)
        val index = if (file.exists()) file.length else 0
        ctx.log.info(s"Got init command for $file at pointer $index")
        replyTo.tell(Sender.StartWithIndex(path, index.toLong))
        Behaviors.same
      case Upload(path, fileSource) =>
        val file = fileAtDestination(path)
        val sink = if (file.exists()) {
          FileIO.toPath(file.toPath, Set(StandardOpenOption.APPEND, StandardOpenOption.WRITE))
        } else {
          FileIO.toPath(file.toPath, Set(StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW, StandardOpenOption.WRITE))
        }
        ctx.log.info(s"Saving file into ${file.toPath}")
        fileSource.runWith(sink)
        Behaviors.same
    }
  }
}
```

Some auxiliary methods

```
val destination: File = Files.createTempDirectory("destination").toFile

def fileAtDestination(file: String) = {
  val name = new File(file).getName
  new File(destination, name)
}

def writeRandomToFile(file: File, size: Int): Unit = {
  val out = new FileOutputStream(file, true)
  (0 until size).foreach { _ =>
    out.write(Random.nextPrintableChar())
  }
  out.close()
}
```

And finally some test code

```
// sender and receiver bootstrapping is omitted

//Create some dummy file to upload
val file: Path = Files.createTempFile("test", "test")
writeRandomToFile(file.toFile, 1000)

//Initiate a new upload
sender.tell(Sender.Upload(file.toAbsolutePath.toString))
// Sleep to allow file upload to finish
Thread.sleep(1000)

//Write more data to the file to emulate a failure
writeRandomToFile(file.toFile, 1000)
//Initiate a new upload that will "recover" from the previous upload 
sender.tell(Sender.Upload(file.toAbsolutePath.toString))
```

Finally, the whole process can be defined as

[image]

Comment: Your solution has been a great help to me.

You explained to me that despite the different programming languages, I could understand them.

I solved it by adding simple code, but it was a big problem for me. ^^;

In the end, I solved the problem.

Thank you.

Comment: @JaeilCho great to hear!

Comment: May I ask you one more question?
Is there a way to stop and resume the file during transfer?
I tried many things, but it didn't work.
Ask for help. :)